# Choose which type of number to represent and safely calculate fractions of quarters, halves

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to calculate with fractions of quarters (0.25), halves (0,25), three quarters and full numbers. There will be no other fractions.

Which type of number should I choose, so that I can safely compare them to zero and do basic addition, substraction, multiplication and division (by full numbers or quarters or halves or three quarters)?

Comment: Are you asking whether you should use `float`, `double`, `NSDecimalNumber`, etc.?

Comment: if you are talking about fixed point math with integers see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)  You are basically asking about Q2. However be aware that multiplies and divides will require shifts maintain Q2.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the documentation for the `NSDecimalNumber` class.

Comment: Multiply everything by 4 and use integers.

Comment: @matt, this is the easiest, smartest and safest thing to do. And I can retrieve the fractions of division by modulus...If you post your solution as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: There’s a lurking problem: one the one hand “there will be no other fractions” and on the other “do basic … multiplication … by … quarters”. So does the OP want to calculate ¼ * ¼?

Answer (score 43):

Use **rational numbers**. That's what the ancient Greeks did. It's what the ancient Babylonians did.

A *rational number* (also commonly called a *fraction*) is a way of representing a number using two integers. One integer is called the *numerator*, the other integer is called the *denominator*. Your case is a degenerate one: the denominator is always 4 (that is, the only fractions you need are quarters). Thus you can ignore the denominator and work entirely with the numerator, which is in your case is an integer representing a *number of quarters*.

In this way, you'll end up doing entirely integer arithmetic.

Comment: Historical note: This is why there are 360 degrees in a circle - it's because the Babylonians found that an implicit denominator of 360 allowed them to represent all commonly needed angles as integers, and thus work with them entirely using integer arithmetic.